# Artifactory OSS 7.46.11 version not getting installed in Windows 10 laptop

Tags: artifactory, failed-installation

I am not able to install JFrog Artifactory OSS version 7.46.11 in my Windows 10 laptop.

I am trying to setup Devops CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins in my laptop for my hands on Devops skills. I tried to setup Artifactory OSS 7.46.11 version in my laptop. However, I am not able to install the software. Even I tried to install as a service but in vain. I have enabled the ports as well. I tried setting up the JVM parameters as mentioned in the JFrog documentation.

Can someone help me in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing the issue while installing Artifactory itself or installation is successful but unable to start it?

you can try the below things.

1. Navigate to `%JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/bin` directory and you will find a file
   Open Power shell and try to run the artifactory.bat file.
   This give you better idea on what is happening.
2. Navigate to `%JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log` folder where the complete logs will be printed. Try to focus on the below log files.

   artifactory-service.log
   access-service.log
   router-service.log

This should reveal some useful information. If you could find anything, share the Error snippet from artifactory-service.log